# Creating a logger decorator, for caesar cipher implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to implement a logger decorator in my caesar cipher implementation in python.

I'm using facade design pattern, and code looks like this:

```
import datetime

from exceptions.shift_lesser_than_0 import ShiftLowerThan0
from functions.decrypt_from_json import DecryptJson
from functions.decrypter import Decrypter
from functions.encrypt_from_json import EncryptJson
from functions.encrypter import Encrypter
from functions.read_json import ReadJson




class Facade:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__is_running = True
        self._history = []
        self.choices = {
            1: self._encrypt_text,
            2: self._decrypt_text,
            3: self._encrypt_from_json,
            4: self._decrypt_from_json,
            5: self._save_to_file,
            9: self._close_app,
        }
        self._start()

    def _start(self):
        """starting application"""
        while self.__is_running:
            self._display_menu()
            self._get_and_execute_user_choice()

    def _display_menu(self):
        menu = """
        1. Encrypt text
        2. Decrypt text
        3. Encrypt from json file
        4. Decrypt from json file
        5. Save all operations to file
        9. Close app
        """
        print(menu)

    def _get_and_execute_user_choice(self):
        try:
            user_choice = int(input("Choose what you want do: "))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            self.choices.get(user_choice, self._show_error)()

    def _encrypt_text(self):
        user_text = input("Enter your text: ")
        shift = self._get_shift()
        try:
            encrypted_text = Encrypter.encrypt_text(text=user_text, shift=shift)
        except ShiftLowerThan0:
            print("Shift value must be higher than 0")
            # logging error
        else:
            print(f"Your encrypted text is: {encrypted_text}")
            self._history.append((user_text, encrypted_text, shift))

    def _decrypt_text(self):
        user_text = input("Enter your text: ")
        shift = self._get_shift()
        try:
            decrypted_text = Decrypter.decrypt_text(text=user_text, shift=shift)
        except ShiftLowerThan0:
            print("shift value must be higher than 0")
        else:
            print(f"Your decrypted text is: {decrypted_text}")
            self._history.append((user_text, decrypted_text, shift))

    def _encrypt_from_json(self):
        user_file = input("Enter the name of the json file: ")
        converted_data = ReadJson.read_json(user_file)
        encrypted_text = EncryptJson.encrypt_from_json(data=converted_data)
        print(f"Encrypted word/words from json is/are: {encrypted_text}")
        self._history.append(
            (
                "Encryption from json",
                converted_data,
                encrypted_text,
                "shown before",
            )
        )

    def _decrypt_from_json(self):
        user_file = input("Enter the name of the json file: ")
        converted_data = ReadJson.read_json(user_file)
        decrypted_text = DecryptJson.decrypt_from_json(data=converted_data)
        print(f"Encrypted word/words from json is/are: {decrypted_text}")
        self._history.append(
            (
                "Encryption from json",
                converted_data,
                decrypted_text,
                "shown before",
            )
        )

    def return_history(self):
        history = []
        for operation in self._history:
            history.append(" ".join(str(element) for element in operation))
        return history

    def _save_to_file(self):
        user_file = input("Enter name of the file you want to save: ")
        with open(user_file, "w") as f:
            for _ in self.return_history():
                f.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}\n")
                f.write(_)
                f.write("\n")

    def _show_error(self):
        raise Exception("Something went wrong")

    def _close_app(self):
        quit()

    def _get_shift(self):
        try:
            shift = int(input("Enter number of shift (max: 31): "))
        except ValueError:
            shift = 0
        return shift


def main():
    Facade()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so i import all functions from another folder, and for e.g encrypter looks like this

```
import string

from exceptions import shift_lesser_than_0

LETTER_RANGE = 26
LETTERS_LOWERCASE = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
LETTERS_UPPERCASE = list(string.ascii_uppercase)


class Encrypter:
    @staticmethod
    def encrypt_text(text: str, shift: int) -> str:
        new_text = ""
        if shift < 0:
            raise shift_lesser_than_0.ShiftLowerThan0
        for char in text:
            if char in LETTERS_LOWERCASE:
                index = LETTERS_LOWERCASE.index(char)
                new_index = index + shift

                if new_index >= LETTER_RANGE:
                    new_index = new_index - LETTER_RANGE
                new_text += LETTERS_LOWERCASE[new_index]
            elif char in LETTERS_UPPERCASE:
                index = LETTERS_UPPERCASE.index(char)
                new_index = index + shift

                if new_index >= LETTER_RANGE:
                    new_index = new_index - LETTER_RANGE
                new_text += LETTERS_UPPERCASE[new_index]
            else:
                new_text += char

        return new_text
```

In exchange for my noob way of adding logs to self._history list, id like to create a decorator, but I have no idea how to pass arguments from function call, to the decorator, I have a pathetic attempt earlier, but it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Here's my attempt at a decorator implementation

```
import inspect

def logger_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logging information about the function call
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        function_name = func.__name__
        log_message = f"[{timestamp}] Function '{function_name}' called"

        # Get the names and values of the function arguments
        signature = inspect.signature(func)
        bound_arguments = signature.bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        bound_arguments.apply_defaults()
        arguments = []
        for name, value in bound_arguments.arguments.items():
            arguments.append(f"{name}={repr(value)}")
        log_message += f" with args: {', '.join(arguments)}"

        # Saving the log message to history
        self._history.append(log_message)

        # Call the original function
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper



def logger_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logging information about the function call
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        function_name = func.__name__
        log_message = f"[{timestamp}] Function '{function_name}' called"

        # Saving the log message to history
        self._history.append(log_message)

        # Call the original function
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

I wanted it to save all arguments, like text, shift, AND results so shifted_text, into `self._history`

Comment: can you specify what you mean by "*it doesnt seem to work correctly*"? what is going wrong viz. what you expected?

Comment: @Hoodlum sure, when i run program, and for e.g do encrypt method twice, with 2 difeerent texts and shifts, and then i use save_to_file method, my saved file looks like this:

"
2023-07-10 22:20:14.834813
[ 2 0 2 3 - 0 7 - 1 0   2 2 : 2 0 : 0 5 . 7 9 8 8 4 3 ]   Functio n   ' _ e n c r y p t _ t e x t '   c a l l e d
2023-07-10 22:20:14.834813
[ 2 0 2 3 - 0 7 - 1 0   2 2 : 2 0 : 0 8 . 3 9 5 1 5 7 ]   F u n c t i o n   ' _ d e c r y p t _ t e x t '   c a l l e d
"

I'd like to have arguemnts listed here. i expected "Function _decrypt_text called with arguemnts: text: "test123", shift: 3

Answer (score 0):

Your logger decorator seems to be fine as it is. The issue is coming from your `return_history` and `_save_to_file` functions, which are not adapted to the format of the logger's history output (which is a single `str` and no longer a tuple).

reducing this the a somewhat smaller example :

```py
import inspect
import datetime

def logger_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Logging information about the function call
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        function_name = func.__name__
        log_message = f"[{timestamp}] Function '{function_name}' called"

        # Get the names and values of the function arguments
        bound_arguments = inspect.signature(func).bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
        bound_arguments.apply_defaults()
        arguments = [f"{name}={value!r}" for name, value in bound_arguments.arguments.items()]
        log_message += f" with args: {', '.join(arguments)}"

        # try to call the original function
        try : 
            retval = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            log_message += f"; returned {retval!r}"
        except Exception as e  :
            log_message += f"; failed with {e.__class__.__name__}:'{e}'"
            raise # keep raising the exception
        finally : 
            # Saving the log message to history, no matter what happens
            self._history.append(log_message)

        return retval

    return wrapper


class A: 
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._history = []

    @logger_decorator
    def foo(self): 
        pass

    @logger_decorator
    def bar(self, *, svar:str, nvar:int=1) -> str:
        return nvar * svar
    
    @logger_decorator
    def sqr_cbe(self, var:int | float) -> tuple: 
        return var**2, var**3
    
    @logger_decorator
    def bad(self): 
        raise RuntimeError("this is a bad function that crashes")
    
    def return_history(self):
        return self._history

    def _save_to_file(self):
        user_file = input("Enter name of the file you want to save: ")
        with open(user_file, "w") as f:
            f.write(f"{datetime.datetime.now()}\n")
            f.write('\n'.join(self._history))

a = A()
a.foo()
a.bar(svar="ma", nvar=2)
a.sqr_cbe(2)
try : 
    a.bad()
except : 
    pass
h = a.return_history()
print(*h, sep='\n')
```

```
[2023-07-11 09:24:34.694729] Function 'foo' called with args: self=<__main__.A object at 0x000002C6505E43D0>; returned None
[2023-07-11 09:24:34.694729] Function 'bar' called with args: self=<__main__.A object at 0x000002C6505E43D0>, svar='ma', nvar=2; returned 'mama'
[2023-07-11 09:24:34.694729] Function 'sqr_cbe' called with args: self=<__main__.A object at 0x000002C6505E43D0>, var=2; returned (4, 8)
[2023-07-11 09:24:34.694729] Function 'bad' called with args: self=<__main__.A object at 0x000002C6505E43D0>; failed with RuntimeError:'this is a bad function that crashes'
```